# How can I replace a variable by another in coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

When I was trying to prove if two functions are equivalent and come to the step:

> I : f(S a') b = S (f a' b)
>
> ---
>
> f (S a') (S b) = S (f a' (S b))

I am wondering whether it's possible to use exact(I) to prove it, namely, to replace (S b) by b, since that's the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

The inference from the premise to the conclusion is generally false for an arbitrary function `f`: consider the function `f a b` such that `f a 0 := a` and `f a (S b) := S b`, you can prove the premise and contradict the conclusion.

You could substitute `b` in `I` only if it was quantified universally in that hypotesis: `I : forall b, f (S a') b = S (f a' b)` ; in that case substituting would amount to application of `I` to `S b`.

If it's not possible to strenghten your hypothesis, you need to use something specific to the function `f` to conclude.